# How to parse json data from cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

```
return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response) -> pplx::task<json::value>
{
    if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        std::cout << "status ok";
        response.headers().set_content_type(L"application/json");

        return response.extract_json();
    }

    // Handle error cases, for now return empty json value... 


    std::cout << "get json data";

    return pplx::task_from_result(json::value());
})
    .then([](pplx::task<json::value> previousTask)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "parse json data";

        const json::value& v = previousTask.get();


        utility::string_t jsonval = v.serialize();

        json::value root;

    //  DisplayJSONValue(v);

       wcout << jsonval;
    //   wcout<<jsonval.data.id;
        // Perform actions here to process the JSON value...

        //std::cout << v;

        //IterateJSONValue();


    }
    catch (const http_exception& e)
    {
        // Print error.
        wostringstream ss;
        ss << e.what() << endl;
        wcout << ss.str();
    }
});
```

}

please help me.thanks in advance.i got api responses.but i cant parse the responses .I can able to call and take the api responses .but not able to parse the responses.
Any steps to parse  the json data ,please help me.

MY API RESPONSES

{"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"1f960b4aa0a7f4e41868d6d9d513ecf8","key":"ABDALLA ELKADY CPA","value":["c1d148.aa.ss.com","53fbbfd1aae9f3b82c89235b8e6bcac28e7a06da1b8aa3ab9164555e543b6f8f"]},{"id":"7ba219914965b79a4a2d9f27d06f1644","key":"callvox","value":["a03096.aa.ss.com","e98cdb61030376461cd75108d082b9e8c5f024b068a3e734744b974442e1cd26"]},{"id":"6ac7f0a7c4affee980a4d5b9b95d6b44","key":"cloudgen","value":["ce39a9.ss.ss.com","f9d507e0ad4b70dbe51d900c2a1aa730eae57d042e805ccf54e153879abe4003"]}

Comment: if you got any solution let me know sir.

Comment: I want to take id from rows.any solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
try
{
    std::cout << "parse json data";
    const json::value& v = previousTask.get();
    utility::string_t jsonval = v.serialize();
    wcout << jsonval;
    auto array = v.at(U("rows")).as_array();
    for (int i = 0; i<array.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto id = array[i].at(U("id")).as_string();
        std::wcout <<"\n"<< id;
        auto key = array[i].at(U("key")).as_string();
        std::wcout <<"\n"<< key;
        auto array2=array[i].at(U("value")).as_array();

        std::wcout << array2[0] << array2[1];
    }
}
catch (const http_exception& e)
{
    wostringstream ss;
    ss << e.what() << endl;
    wcout << ss.str();
}
```

Above solution work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the `wcout`, helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
const json::value& v = previousTask.get();
auto a = v[L"rows"].as_array();
for (auto i= a.begin();i!=a.end();i++)
{
auto id = (*i)[L"ID"]
}
```

Comment: .can you share your skype id. my skype id prince tomy.

Comment: .sir your skype id

Comment: can you please put the whole error message, on which line exactly the error appears?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
auto array = json.at(U("devices")).as_array();
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); ++i)
{
     auto id = array[i].at(U("id")).as_string();
     auto type = array[i].at(U("type")).as_string();
}
```

Comment: oooh, sorry keep trying.